# Eclipse becomes slow when project contains many links (cause: bad network share in build path)

Tags: eclipse, performance

We have in one of our applications a single eclipse project that contains all the code. I think it is a fair amount of code - not a small project, but not a huge one either. I ran a small check on it and got:

> Found <4245> code files
>   Totaling <421557> lines of code

This check includes any code lines that are not empty or just containing `{` or `}`.

So it is not a huge project - however, the `.project` defines many links to mask the real directory structure to create a different view for the `Package Explorer` - so the project will make more sense.

The problem is that `eclipse` is working very slow in some areas.
Examples:

- Find references in workspace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) - Takes a very long time compared to previous projects I worked on in this magnitude
- Decompilation via `jadclipse` or `JDEclipse` can take as much as 1 minute - causing `eclipse` to show the lovely **(Not Responding)** suffix on the title-bar. Same code decompiled from outside of `eclipse` takes less than a second.
- JUnit test execution - the initiation of the execution takes over 10 seconds, in which `eclipse` doesn't seem to do anything important.

Any ideas why this could happen and if it can be a result of a "complex" project structure?

Using `eclipse 3.6`, without many plug-ins installed.

**EDIT:**

Using `resmon` eventually showed me the problem. I noticed that eclipse keeps trying to connect to a network share - it didn't take much CPU or IO, but still it was there.
When inspecting the `.classpath` file I noticed this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="build_class" sourcepath="some share using samba ...">
```

The share we were referencing wasn't even a correct path, but that probably caused a lot of overhead in every activity.

Removing the `sourcepath` attachment and leaving it as:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="build_class">
```

Solved the problem immediately. Since we were using a decompiler plug-in any way, we were not harmed by this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical of a situation with one or more resource bottlenecks.

You will need to investigate with operating system tools what Eclipse is waiting for (Task Manager, and perfmon are great for Windows), and if that doesn't help investigate Eclipse itself with jvisualvm in the Oracle 6 JDK.

You will most likely find that the system is waiting for the underlying harddisk.  This can have several reasons, some being:

- Eclipse is a big program.  The operating system may need to swap parts of it out to disk.  For Eclipse this ruins performance.  Really!
- Eclipse needs a *lot* of disk access.  If you have a slow disk or (horrors of horrors) an overly aggressive anti-virus program, this also ruins performance.  If the operating system has plenty of spare RAM it can cache files in memory giving better performance.

If this is the case, get more RAM.

If the underlying system is fine, but Eclipse on its own is very slow (but other Java programs run fine), then see with jvisualvm how memory usage is behaving over time, and if you have many, frequent garbage collections when you need to wait, you may need to allocate more memory to the JVM.  This is done in the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Also if you use Windows and the disk is the bottleneck I believe using ReadyBoost with a suitable USB-key can improve performance.

Comment: What if this is limited to a single project? I tried several other projects (separate workspaces) and none of them suffered from this problem. You still think `jvisualvm` can help?

Comment: If it is only a single project, you have found a difference _inside_ Eclipse triggering this.  My guess would be that jvisualvm would show that the Eclipse JVM behaves as described.

Comment: `jvisualvm` hangs whenever my `Eclipse` is up ... not even related to the project being open or not. Even in the `workspace selection` screen - it just hangs.

Comment: Try invoking Eclipse with the JRE enclosed in the JDK.  If this doesn't help now might be a good time to figure out what is broken in your system and fix it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Try invoking Eclipse with the JRE enclosed in the JDK". Do you mean tell Eclipse to load with the JDK instead of the JRE? I'm starting eclipse this way: `"C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw" -clean` (For Maven to work properly)

Comment: That is what I mean.  And jvisualvm in the same folder does not attach to the eclipse process?

Comment: Yes - I use the same JDK to lunch jvisualvm. It sees the Eclipse process, but hangs the minute I click on it. It doesn't hang entirely - it allows me to move and resize the jvisualvm window - but other than that I cannot switch the focus to any other process or click on any menu item/tool bar button. It behaves as if a dialog is open and I cannot see it (but there isn't one open).

Comment: Thanks - this wasn't memory related - I found the problem. `resmon` eventually showed me the answer :)

Comment: Good you found it.  So the unresponsiveness was because an illegal network share was used, and Windows kept trying to find it.

Comment: Exactly - I blamed `eclipse` too early :)